# how to separate files for mocha-webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

What's happening is that when I run my tests, my coverage only shows `bundle.js` which isn't that helpful.

I have the following webpack file setup and wanted to know what I should change to make it so that each file is covered individually

**webpack.config-test.js**

```
var nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"],
        alias: {
            "@": path.join(__dirname, "../../src/server"),
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: "./",
        filename: "[name].js",
    },    
    target: "node", // webpack should compile node compatible code
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
}
```

running the command via npm:

```
nyc mocha-webpack --webpack-config test/server/webpack.config-test.js --glob \"*spec.js\" test/server/unit
```

The output currently is:

```
All files  |    90.38 |    70.83 |    90.91 |     90.2 |                   |
 bundle.js |    90.38 |    70.83 |    90.91 |     90.2 |... 78,280,282,306
```

whereas I'm expecting the output to be

```
All files     |       80 |    68.75 |       80 |       80 |                   |
 functions.js |    78.79 |    68.75 |       80 |    78.79 |... 59,60,62,64,88 |
 mixin.js     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |
```

In the non mocha-webpack version, I also added the filename to each test, and I would like that to also happen in the webpack version. So **without** webpack, I run on an index.js, i.e.

**index.js**

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
files.forEach(file => 
{
    if (!file.match(/\.spec\.js$/))
        return

    console.log(file)

    describe(file, function () 
    {
        require(path.join(__dirname, file))
    })
})
```

which then outputs something like:

```
  sql.spec.js
    Some SQL tests
      ✓ should be 10

  test.spec.js
    generateRandomString
      ✓ should generate a 20 length string
      ✓ should generate a 40 length string
      ✓ should throw error for -10
      ✓ should throw error for length
    getRequiredProps
      ✓ should get prop
      ✓ should throw error
    toTime
      ✓ 1 seconds should return 1000
      ✓ 1 minutes should return 60000
      ✓ 1 hours should return 3600000
      ✓ 1 days should return 86400000
```

**Update**

There's source-mapping, but it's showing a lot more than I'd like: https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack/blob/master/docs/installation/webpack-configuration.md

```
------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                                      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                                 |     78.8 |    54.72 |    87.27 |     78.7 |                   |
 .tmp/mocha-webpack/1532582562486/webpack |    95.45 |       75 |    83.33 |    95.24 |                   |
  bootstrap 4e654663ecc955703de0          |    95.45 |       75 |    83.33 |    95.24 |                49 |
 node_modules/mocha-webpack/lib           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  entry.js                                |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 src/server                               |       64 |    48.65 |       70 |       64 |                   |
  db.js                                   |    45.61 |    26.32 |    45.45 |    45.61 |... 20,122,126,138 |
  functions.js                            |    84.85 |    72.22 |      100 |    84.85 |    42,58,59,60,87 |
  mixin.js                                |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  mock.js                                 |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 src/server/post                          |       75 |     62.5 |      100 |       75 |                   |
  maptool.js                              |       75 |     62.5 |      100 |       75 |... 41,148,158,159 |
 test/server/unit                         |    98.33 |      100 |      100 |    98.33 |                   |
  functions.spec.js                       |    96.97 |      100 |      100 |    96.97 |                67 |
  maptool.spec.js                         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  mock.spec.js                            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  sql.spec.js                             |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

How would I reduce it so that only the files being checked are outputted?

Comment: Thus is a good question but, personally, I prefer the unbundled form for many reasons.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes, I like the unbundled form, that's my intention. I just don't know how to do it with webpack. I'm sure there's a way since I'm using vue-cli which does proper code splitting and chunking and stuff that I don't fully understand lol.

Comment: Webpack is a bundler by definition. Tools like RequireJS and SystemJS apply bundling as an optimization but operate in terms of individual files by default. That said I believe you may want to look at how tools like karma integrate into Webpack.

Comment: yeah, karma seems to show all the file differences. But I read somewhere that you can't use Karma for node (backend).

Comment: @AluanHaddad Seems like there's source mapping in built already, but I'm not sure how it's supposed to be used. See edit

Comment: @AluanHaddad ah worked it out, simple addition. But I still want those filenames in my `describe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would I reduce it so that only the files being checked are outputted?

It looks like even your `spec` files are not exluded from coverage report.
Try to provide paths to the files that will be included in the coverage report in `nyc` config. In your `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "nyc": {
    "include": [
      "src/server/**/*.js"
    ],
    ...
   },
   ...
}
```

If it does not help try to instrument your code with `instanbul-instrumenter-loader`, provide paths for files to be covered in loader rule in your webpack config:

```
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: { loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader' },
          include: path.resolve('../../src/server')
        }
      ]
}
```

and `nyc` default instrumenter should be disabled with `instrument: false` in `nyc` config.

**UPDATE**

As another solution if you are using Babel(and Vue) it make sense to instrument code with `babel-plugin-istanbul` it creates correct mapping (by the way I could not make `istanbul-instrumenter-loader` work with babel webpack configuration correctly).

I recommend to see [vue-test-utils-mocha-webpack-example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils-mocha-webpack-example) even you have no Vue dependency but use Babel.

Hope it helps.

Related resource: [Code coverage for mocha-webpack](https://zinserjan.github.io/mocha-webpack/docs/guides/code-coverage.html)

Comment: the only part left is how do I add an extra describe before each file, i.e. `test.spec.js` followed by all its tests

Comment: @A.Lau what is output when you run `index.js` instead of spec files like this `nyc mocha-webpack --webpack-config test/server/webpack.config-test.js test/server/unit/index.js`?

Comment: It's already been posted above. Sorry misread. It outputs 0 tests

Comment: @A.Lau I tried to get filename or preprocess test files somehow but there is now simple way to achieve what you want I think(dynamically add file names to tests).  As solution you can just add `describe` block to each file and write file name manually, other approaches are too painful.

Comment: another issue is that, if an error does happen, it still only references bundle.js rather than the individual file. :\

Comment: @A.Lau I updated answer with "UPDATE" section, this is the most workable configuration, but unfortunately I havn't any thoughts about your issue. However config with instanbul plagin for babel shows correct file with line on test failed, you can download repo and check.